# Требуется ли запятая после слова "усилий"?

Tags: пунктуация

"После недолгих усилий пробку удалось продавить по горлышку и вытащить записку".

Answer (score 1):

Нет, запятая не нужна. "После недолгих усилий" относится к сказуемому в предложении и уточняет время совершения действия. "Удалось продавить" когда? - "после недолгих усилий".

"После недолгих усилий" не является ни уточнением, ни деепричастным оборотом. Таким образом, запятая после слова "усилий" не нужна, в том числе и по смыслу.